# Changing a value within SQL search query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a valid query which pulls back 'stores' related to a particular 'site'. Some stores are related to multiple sites.

```
**602 = site1**

store   602
store2  602
store3  602
```

Is there a way, within my query, to label 602 with 'site1' so that it looks like 602(site1). So then it would show:

```
store   602(site1)
store2  602(site1)
store3  602(site1)
```

My query is below:

```
SELECT BS.PK, BS.p_uid, O.p_salesoffice, Count(O.Code)
FROM orders AS O
JOIN basestore AS BS ON O.p_store = BS.PK
WHERE (BS.PK = '8796093056989' AND O.p_salesoffice IN (602, 177))
GROUP BY BS.p_uid, O.p_salesoffice
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's no correlation between your query and your desired result. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You have 3 tables sites,stores and orders?

Comment: no 2 tables. stores and orders are both within Orders table and sites is in basestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `concat` as you said you need only for 602 so use `case when`

```
    select PK,
    p_uid, 
    case when p_salesoffice=602 then concat(p_salesoffice,' (site1)')  
    else  p_salesoffice end  as salesoffice,
    Cnt 
    from 
   (     
    SELECT BS.PK as PK, BS.p_uid as p_uid, O.p_salesoffice as p_salesoffice, Count(O.Code) as Cnt
    FROM orders AS O
    JOIN basestore AS BS ON O.p_store = BS.PK
    WHERE (BS.PK = '8796093056989' AND O.p_salesoffice IN (602, 177))
    GROUP BY BS.p_uid, O.p_salesoffice
    ) as T
```

Comment: I cant because that will apply to all stores, I only want it to apply to 602

Comment: i have edited answer can you check please @user1227124

Comment: thank you but its now broken my query
-
SELECT BS.PK, BS.p_uid,
CASE WHEN 0.p_salesoffice=602 THEN concat(O.p_salesoffice,'(site1)')
ELSE  O.p_salesoffice END as 0.p_salesoffice, Count(O.Code)
FROM orders AS O

Comment: @user1227124 broken??

Comment: Yes. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'p_salesoffice=602 THEN concat(O.p_salesoffice,'(site1)') ELSE O.p_salesoffice E' at line 2

Comment: @user1227124 could you please give me fiddle link where i can see error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177488/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-user1227124).